# xamarin.android - scrolling is working when onTouch listener is attached to gridview or recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

Sorry if this question is has been already asked earlier, but I couldn't find it. so thought to ask here.

I am simply doing this in my `onCreate` of my activity. I implemented `View.IOnTouchListner` in my activity

```
 _gridGallery.SetOnTouchListner(this)
```

Or

```
_recyclerView.SetOnTouchListner(this)
```

but whenever I try this my `OnTouch` event gets called as usual but my gridview or recyclerview doesn't scroll at all. But if I remove this line scrolling and all other things work fine. There must be my mistake. Is there anything I am missing ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could we see the implemented classes for that interface that you're using, should be the 'OnTouch' method. It's likely something is not being done correctly in that method, causing it to block scroll events.

Comment: Hello, Digitalsa1nt, I am not at my working place right now. will update you with detailed code tomorrow. But in short, I am finding correct recyclerview from the view, set `GridLayoutManager` to recycler view with column count 4, assign `RecyclerView.Adapter` to recyclerview(with RecyclerView.ViewHolder). And `OnTouch` I am getting correct view according to x and y position, then find its index in adapter(as I don't remember method name), from that finding viewholder and then change imageview.

Comment: Hi, we need check your `OnTouch` method.